# Difference normal cast and pointer cast

Tags: pointers, casting

i've written a following code:

```
void union_bytes() {
    float fnum = 1209.1996f;
    union endian {
        float fnum;
        int inum;
        unsigned char cnum[4];
    }instance;
    instance.fnum = fnum;
    printf("Number = %f\nLittle Endian = %.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x\nHex = %x\n", instance.fnum, instance.cnum[0],
        instance.cnum[1], instance.cnum[2], instance.cnum[3], instance.inum);
}

void pointer_bytes() {
    float fnum = 1209.1996f;
    int *ptr_inum = (int*)&fnum;;
    unsigned char *cbytes = (unsigned char *)&fnum;
    printf("Number = %f\nLittle Endian = %.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x\nHex = %x\n", fnum, cbytes[0], cbytes[1], cbytes[2], cbytes[3], *ptr_inum);

}
```

and i want to know, why i have to do such things : `int *ptr_inum = (int*)&fnum;` in order to get little-endian, and i cant do so like this:

```
int inum = (int)fnum;
```

i suppose, the last option forces fnum to lose some bytes, but i still dont know how such numbers are represent in memory(and which bytes are exactly to lose).

Why in this case:

```
unsigned char ch[4] = { 0x3b, 0x51, 0x7a, 0x24 };
float f = *(float*)ch;
```

When comes to casting, ch doesnt give the first nible 0x3b which is then a float, rather than it converts all the bytes in table compounding the entire float.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why i have to do such things : int *ptr_inum = (int*)&fnum; in order
>   to get little-endian, and i cant do so like this: int inum =
>   (int)fnum;

There is some terminology confusion here. [Little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is a specific order of bytes for multi-byte structures, and is usually mentioned as opposed to big-endian.

What you are getting is as a result of execution of the **first statement** is:
make the variable that points to integer point to a location where a floating-point number is stored, so that later its word representation can be retrieved/modifed int by int. Say, for number 1.9 in IEEE-754 compliant implementations [is represented as](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) 0x3ff33333, so on little-endian architectures if your int is 32bit you would get 0x3ff33333.

**Second statement** would mean: give me an integer variable, that results from a float pointing number. By standard, that means dropping of the decimal, so out of 1.9 you will get 1.

Comment: so i suppose here:                   unsigned char ch[4] = { 0x3b, 0x51, 0x7a, 0x24 };
float f = *(float*)ch;                     the compiler is filling the remaining bytes with next bytes, because it can fill up to 4 bytes?

Comment: ch is a const pointer to unsigned char, so (float)ch is an attempt to convert a pointer (i.e. an address) to float. This makes very little sense and is illegal.

Comment: If you meant `*(float*)ch`, then computer will try to interpret those 4 bytes as some float number (5.4278914E-17 in this case)